# Dynamically create a lightning component and put it into a custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dynamic

Is it possible to dynamically create a lightning component and put it into a custom lightning component?

For example, I have the following custom lightning component:

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere">

        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

And I have a component which statically I would add in the following way:

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere">
            <namespace:MyComponent myArg="{!v.myArg}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

How could I add the line `<namespace:MyComponent myArg="{!v.myArg}"/>` dynamically from client-side controller?

I am aware of everything written [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm). It does not help me to solve the problem, so I am posting it here.

**UPDATE**

In order to show why addition of `{!body}` confuses me I will tweak the code a little bit.

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the first component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere1">
            <namespace:MyComponent myArg="{!v.myArg}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the second component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere2">
            <namespace:MyComponent myArg="{!v.myArg}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Not only the component I am setting in place of `{!v.body}`, but also the `{!v.body}` and `aura:id` for encompassing element should be generated at runtime.

Comment: Yes it is and the link you have included includes the relevant material. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @KeithC, could you, please, provide a JavaScript code to accomplish this? Since I can follow only examples in documentation and do not know how to add the component without having a `{!v.body}`.

Comment: What is stopping you adding a `{!v.body}`?

Comment: @KeithC, I can have multiple places in my custom lightning component where I would like to add another lightning component. Let me update the question to elaborate this.

Comment: You're allowed to have more than one [facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_facets.htm) (attribute of type `Aura.Component[]`), beyond just `v.body`.

Comment: Many of the standard components do (for example, `<lightning:card>` has multiple facets), and this would allow you to achieve your stated objective.

Comment: @DavidReed, adding `{!v.body}` at runtime produces a bare text and when I try to set `aura:id` at runtime it just does not appear at all. I think I am missing something important here. I will update a question a little bit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Lightning attribute like `v.body`, which is typed as `Aura.Component[]`, is called a [facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_facets.htm). It's perfectly legal to have multiple facets in your component.

You'd have to do something more like this, if I may modify your example component to suit. Note the `Aura.Component[]`-typed attributes: these *behave like* `v.body` in that they hold dynamically-instantiated Lightning components, but you can place them as you please and have more than one as needed.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute type="Aura.Component[]" name="firstPanel" />
    <aura:attribute type="Aura.Component[]" name="secondPanel" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }" />
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the first component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere1">
            {! v.firstPanel }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wasCreatedDynamicallyInCode">
        Here should go the second component:
        <div id="addALightningComponentHere2">
            {! v.secondPanel }
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Then, in your JavaScript controller, you'd do something like the below (adapted from the [linked documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm), and omitting error handling and action handler body for clarity):

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": "Press Me First",
                "onclick": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new button to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var firstPanel = cmp.get("v.firstPanel");
                    firstPanel.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.firstPanel", firstPanel);
                }

            }
        );
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": "Press Me Second",
                "onclick": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new button to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var secondPanel = cmp.get("v.secondPanel");
                    secondPanel.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.secondPanel", secondPanel);
                }

            }
        );
    },
    handlePress: function(component, event, helper) {

    }
})
```

Now, if what you need is a dynamically determined number of dynamic component slots in something like an iteration, that might be a situation that calls for decomposing this component into a suite of more elemental components (which themselves might or might not contain facets) rather than building it all into a single massive component, or following the example (again in the linked documentation) that dynamically instantiates children of dynamically instantiated components.

That said, in most cases it *seems* to be better design to decompose components and conditionally render rather than using very deep dynamic instantiation.